# Find difference between two table in SQL and append back result to source table & update column values only for newly inserted rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, difference

I am new to SQL Server. I want to create a procedure which should check difference between master table & quarterly table and insert the different rows back to the master table and update the corresponding column values.

Master table is like:

### |PID  | Release_date | Retired_date

|loc12|202108        |
|loc34|202108        |

Quaterly table is like:

### |PID  | Address      | Post_code

|loc12| Srinagar     | 5678
|loc34| Girinagar    | 6789
|loc45| RRnagar      | 7890
|loc56| Bnagar       | 9012

Resultant Master table should be like:

### |PID  | Release_date | Retired_date

|loc12|202108        |
|loc34|202108        |
|loc45|202111        |
|loc56|202111        |

I have tried except but I'm not able to update the master table after inserting the difference. My code is

```
insert into master(select PID from Master
                   except
                   select PID from Quaterly)
update master
set Release_date = '202111'
where PID in (select PID from Master
              except
              select PID from Quaterly)
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do everything in one query, no need to use UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO Master(PID, Release_date)
SELECT q.PID, '202111'
FROM Quaterly q
WHERE q.PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM Master)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other approach you can use by leveraging SQL JOINs:

```
INSERT INTO MASTER
SELECT q2.PID, '202111'
FROM Quaterly q1
LEFT JOIN Quaterly q2
ON q1.PID = q2.PID
WHERE q1.PID IS NULL
```